# A difficult integration that contains $e^{tx} x^{\alpha - 1}(1-x)^{\beta -1}$ .

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I integrate this integral:
 $$\int^{1}_{0} e^{tx} x^{\alpha - 1}(1-x)^{\beta -1}dx.$$
Could anyone give me a hint ?

Comment: With exponentials and power functions in the integrand, I would first try integration by parts.

Comment: How will you choose u & v in the integration by parts?@MatthewLeingang

Comment: are you interested in a Maple Output?

Comment: I do not understand @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: I don't know if you lnow about probability distributions but $x^{\alpha - 1}(1-x)^{\beta -1}$ is the kernel of a Beta distribution, then if you multiply by a 1 in a clever way you get that what you want to calculate is precisely the moment generator function of a Beta distribution of parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta $, it may be computed used properties of Beta function.
The resultant function is called Kummel's confluent hypergeometric function (of first kind)

Comment: How can I multiply by 1 in a clever way ? @Jonathaniui

Comment: The answer below is precissely what I was talking about. The clever way is $1=\frac  {B(a,b)}{B (a,b)} $.

Comment: what about the $e^{tx}$@Jonathaniui

Comment: You asked for hints, and you got several.  A Math Lover should be able to take a few more steps on their own.

Comment: okay thank u for your help @MatthewLeingang

Comment: The integral can be expressed in terms of the $\,\mathrm{M_{\kappa,\,\mu}}$
[Whittaker Function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.16.E1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression is $B(\alpha, \beta) \mathbf{E} e^{tX}$ where $X\sim Beta(\alpha, \beta)$.

Where $X\sim Beta(\alpha,\beta)$ if the pdf of X is $\frac{x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}}{Beta(\alpha,\beta)}$.

Note that moments are easy to calculate, $\mathbf{E} X^n = \int_0^1{\frac{x^{n+\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}}{Beta(\alpha,\beta)}}dx=\frac{Beta(\alpha+n,\beta)}{Beta(\alpha,\beta)}=\frac{\Gamma(a+b)\Gamma(a+n)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\alpha+\beta+n)}=\frac{\alpha(\alpha+1) ... (\alpha+n-1)}{(\alpha+\beta)(\alpha+\beta+1)...(\alpha+\beta+n-1)}=\frac{\alpha^{(n)}}{(\alpha+\beta)^{(n)}}$

Using the fact that $e^{tX}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^nX^n}{n!}$, and integrating term by term as above, we get $\mathbf{E}e^{tX}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\alpha^{(n)}}{(\alpha+\beta)^{(n)}} \frac{t^n}{n!}$.

Thus your original integral is $B(\alpha, \beta) \mathbf{E} e^{tX}=B(\alpha,\beta)\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\alpha^{(n)}}{(\alpha+\beta)^{(n)}} \frac{t^n}{n!}$

Comment: The OP asked for a **hint** and you give a full solution.  I find that inappropriate.

Comment: Sorry, I do this primarily for myself - it is relaxing sometimes to do some math when I need a break. I don't concern myself usually with if OP just needs a hint, or if she has done homework, or if it is spoon feeding. I do it for me.

Comment: I don't find that argument convincing, because if you "do this primarily for myself," then there is no need for you to share the solution by posting the answer.  Furthermore, that you claim to be self-interested is not, in my view, an adequate defense for not only going against the specific request of the OP, but also what are the established community guidelines.

Comment: I am not going to continue debating this here. If you would like I can share my email and we can continue discussing this separately.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, here's a hint:  [Beta Distribution Moment Generating Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Moment_generating_function)

That's all you'll get from me, though, because you've not provided any of your own thoughts or effort.